# Makefile filename convention

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I want to compile my C program using `gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)` compiler on Windows 10 64-bit using make file. When I named the make file as `makefile` or `Makefile`, it compiled successfully. But, when I named it as `MAKEFILE`, it failed and this error showed:

```
mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

What I wanna ask is this error happened only on Windows machine or the convention forbid `MAKEFILE' for make file filename?

Answer (score 6):

`GNU make` uses makefile named `makefile` or `Makefile` by default. If it does not find such files it complains.

You can manually specify makefile filename if it differs for this convention like that:

```
make -f MAKEFILE
```

Comment: Note that, strictly speaking, the order is [GNUmakefile, makefile then Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names).

Comment: Strange...because on windows filenames are case insensitive, so gnu trying to open `makefile` will find any case version of `MaKeFiLe`